# "Subscription validation request failed. Response must exactly match validationToken query parameter."

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

I have the requirement to enable a subscription for change notifications for OneDrive (me/drive/SharedWithMe) but it is giving error when I post the payload.

When I change the resource to OneDrive( me/drive/root) which Microsoft API recommends for subscriptions but that also giving error.

I set up the API permission for the app. Few of the application permission which needs admin consent but could not be done for the current user.  User grants are given below.

I have created ngrok URL to redirect webserver http://localhost:5000 /notify to ngrok URL.  This is mentioned in the payload for posting for a new subscription. Python code also is given below.

I want to know what is the prerequisite for the enabling subscription. Please provide light on license requirement, API permission and scopes, resource group, and azure key vault. This requirement is for OneDrive storage subscription.

Document referenced:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/samples/microsoftgraph/aspnetcore-webhook-with-resource-data/sample-application---microsoft-graph-change-notifications/

When we are posting the payload for new subscriptions, it is giving error.

payload:
{
"changeType": "updated",
"notificationUrl": "https://d76209350b89.ngrok.io/notify",
"resource": "me/drive/root",
"expirationDateTime": "2020-07-24T18:23:45.9356913Z",
"clientState": "secretClientValue",
"latestSupportedTlsVersion": "v1_2"
}

subscriptions:
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/subscriptions

```
{
    "error": {
        "code": "InvalidRequest",
        "message": "Subscription validation request failed. Response must exactly match validationToken query parameter.",
        "innerError": {
            "date": "2020-07-22T16:45:41",
            "request-id": "d5d7f05b-9f3d-44a9-a74a-9f21e3c8a9ba"
        }
    }
}
```

Endpoint that receives the validation request

```
    enter code here:
    http_header={'Authorization':f'Bearer 
    {token_response["accessToken"]}','Content-type':'application/json'}
    print(http_header)
    post_data={
    "changeType": "updated",
    "notificationUrl": REDIRECT_URI_2,
    "resource": "me/drive/root",
    "expirationDateTime": "2020-07-22T18:23:45.9356913Z",
    "clientState": "secretClientValue",
    "latestSupportedTlsVersion": "v1_2"
    }
res=requests.post('https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/subscriptions',headers=http_header,data=post_data)
```

Receives the change notifications

```
@app.route("/notify",methods=['GET','POST'])
    def onedrive():
    valtoken=flask.request.args.get('validationToken')
    valtok=valtoken.replace(':','%3a')
    valt=valtok.replace(' ','+')
    subscribe_url = f'https://062dece903f6.ngrok.io/notify?validationToken={valt}  HTTP/1.1'
    resp = flask.Response(status=200)
    resp.headers['content-type']="plain/text"
    resp.headers['token']=valt
    resp.headers['location'] = subscribe_url
    return resp
```

I am developing in Python. Anyone has done this before please share.

Thanks.

Comment: I think the code for the endpoint that receives the validation request and receives the change notifications is missing, can you include it please?

Comment: the endpoint that receives the validation request

Comment: endpoint that receives the validation request
http_header={'Authorization':f'Bearer {token_response["accessToken"]}','Content-type':'application/json'}
print(http_header)
post_data={
"changeType": "updated",
"notificationUrl": REDIRECT_URI_2,
"resource": "me/drive/root",
"expirationDateTime": "2020-07-22T18:23:45.9356913Z",
"clientState": "secretClientValue",
"latestSupportedTlsVersion": "v1_2"}
res=requests.post('https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/subscriptions',headers=http_header,data=post_data)

Comment: please edit your original post to include the code. This way we'll get formatting and everything

Comment: receives the change notifications
@app.route("/notify",methods=['GET','POST'])
def onedrive():
valtoken=flask.request.args.get('validationToken')
valtok=valtoken.replace(':','%3a')
valt=valtok.replace(' ','+')
subscribe_url = f'https://062dece903f6.ngrok.io/notify?validationToken={valt}  HTTP/1.1'
resp = flask.Response(status=200)
resp.headers['content-type']="plain/text"
resp.headers['token']=valt
resp.headers['location'] = subscribe_url
return resp

Comment: @baywet- We are following what you asked. Code given below @APP.route("/notify",methods=['GET','POST']) def onedrive(): print("started onedrive") valtoken=flask.request.args.get('validationToken') ##valt=urllib.parse.quote_plus(valtoken) print (valtoken,200,{'content-type':'text/plain'}) return valtoken,200,{'content-type':'plain/text'} Token receiving as: "POST /notify?validationToken=Validation%3a+Testing+client+application+reachability+for+subscription+Request-Id%3a+3ca9c029-6269-1312-5961-08da5ca4f8a3 HTTP/1.1" 200 Error remain the same

Answer (score 0):

The content type should be `text/plain`. The validation token value should be returned as the response body and not a header. There's no need for a location header.

Also: I'm not sure why you are replacing characters but you should simply url decode and return as is.

Answer (score 0):

```
@app.route("/notify",methods=['POST'])
def onedrive():
    valtoken=flask.request.args.get('validationToken')
    
    resp=app.response_class(response=urllib.parse.unquote(valtoken),status=200,mimetype='plain/text')
    return resp
```

Comment: I tested with the above code but still getting error.

Comment: When i'm posting the payload for new subscriptions, it is giving error code 400. 

payload:
{
"changeType": "updated",
"notificationUrl": "https://d76209350b89.ngrok.io/notify",
"resource": "me/drive/root",
"expirationDateTime": "2020-07-24T18:23:45.9356913Z",
"clientState": "secretClientValue",
"latestSupportedTlsVersion": "v1_2"
}

subscriptions:
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/subscriptions

Comment: http_header={'Authorization':f'Bearer {token_response["accessToken"]}','Content- 
     type':'application/json'}
    
        post_data={
        "changeType": "updated",
        "notificationUrl": REDIRECT_URI_2,
         "resource": "me/drive/root",
         "expirationDateTime": "2020-07-22T18:23:45.9356913Z",
         "clientState": "secretClientValue",
         "latestSupportedTlsVersion": "v1_2"
        }
    
 res=requests.post('https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/subscriptions',headers=http_header,data=post_data)

Comment: my requests.post() is returning 400 error code. I'm not able to figure it out if my subscription set up is correct. Is there any license requirement for subscriptions api to enable for onedrive.  Please guide me on the specifics of license,scope and ngrok redirect url is good for subscription webhook.

Comment: @baywet- We are following what you asked. Code given below
@APP.route("/notify",methods=['GET','POST'])
def onedrive():
    print("started onedrive")
    valtoken=flask.request.args.get('validationToken')
    ##valt=urllib.parse.quote_plus(valtoken)    
    print (valtoken,200,{'content-type':'text/plain'})
    return valtoken,200,{'content-type':'plain/text'}
Token receiving as:  "POST /notify?validationToken=Validation%3a+Testing+client+application+reachability+for+subscription+Request-Id%3a+3ca9c029-6269-1312-5961-08da5ca4f8a3 HTTP/1.1" 200
Error remain the same

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer . Good luck

Answer (score 0):

```
valtoken=request.args.get('validationToken')
resp=app.response_class(valtoken,status=200,content_type="text/plain")
return resp
```

Answer (score 0):

```
from urllib.parse import unquote
from flask import Flask, request, make_response

app = Flask("__init__")

@app.route("/", methods=["GET", "POST"])
def main():
    validation = unquote(request.args.get("validationToken"))
    resp = make_response(validation, 200)
    resp.headers["Content-Type"] = "text/plain; charset=utf-8"
    return resp

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug=True, host="0.0.0.0", port=5000)
```

Then im just using ngrok

```
ngrok http 5000
```

And using the public URL in my subscription request